# Unable to resolve pyodbc dependency error while migrating SQL Server database to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, migration, mysql-workbench, python

I am using MySQL workbench 8.0.35 to Migrate Database from SQL Server to MySQL.
I have installed python 3.12.0 and pyodbc 5.0.1.
When i select Start Migration in the MySQL workbench i am getting pyodbc dependency error as shown below.
How do we resolve this error.
[image: pyodbc error]

[image: python]

Any help is highly appreciated.